# Типографское название длинного тире

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Каково типографское название символа ***длинное тире***?

*P.S. Слово в голове крутится, как и «потолочный плинтус», а вспомнить — не могу.*

Comment: ExMuser, длинное тире – издательский термин. Вы хотите спросить, есть ли у него другое название?

Comment: Именно что хочу, как этот символ называется. Это как название потолочного плинуса..

Comment: Тире так и называется, как минимум, с 1899 года. Может, вы слово "шпация" или какое-то другое пытаетесь вспомнить?

Answer (score 5):

В типографике *длинное тире* ещё называют «эм-дэш», «m-dash» согласно ширине буквы M. Сам термин появился вслед за появлением значения короткого (среднего) тире, равного ширине буквы N. Больше информации здесь: https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/97/

Потолочный элемент, обрамление потолка по периметру, может называться карнизом, багетом, тягой, консолью, штапиком — в зависимости от профиля и функции.

Answer (score 2):

Если вопрос в том, почему и на что поправили, то поправили напрасно. "Длинное тире" - термин профессиональный, но достаточно понятный и распространенный.

Английские аналоги куда менее известны широкому кругу.

Ну а если вопрос "про вообще", то, строго говоря, есть (или было) шесть видов значка серединной черточки между словами и знаками, включая дефис, который считается самостоятельным орфографическим знаком и "черту-отбивку" - специальный значок для рисования сплошной черты. Вот у последнего значка действительно было какое-то "правильное" название, не могу вспомнить, но просто "отбивка" это нечто другое, поэтому - не путать!

Дефис
Минус
Короткое тире
Среднее тире
Длинное тире
Горизонтальная черта (интервальная).
*- от коротких к длинным*.

Различаются они не столько длиной, сколько своей функцией, при этом ни одна издательская система различия по длине в полном виде не поддерживает. В результате возникают разночтения. Так, минус (а иногда и дефис) называют коротким тире, а среднее - коротким. Спорить бессмысленно, надо просто понять, к какой из "научных школ" принадлежит ваш собеседник.

В самом простом случае  достаточно знака одной длины - как вот на форумах - нет нужды различать тире и дефис (дефисом считается то, что не имеет пробелов вокруг), а в издательских системах обычно имеют три знака - дефис и два тире, иногда минус выступает как самостоятельный знак.

Все это - дела издательские и типографские, к русскому языку и его правилам имеет весьма косвенное отношение.

Хорошую ссылку на Арт. Лебедева вам уже дал shampar. Я только уточню, что это личное мнение Лебедева, но говорит он тут, имхо, вполне по делу.

(----)
"Потолочный плинтус" - багет. Но это тоже менее известный термин, хотя тут надо признать, что он более правильный.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, камрад. Вам бы на АШ поселиться, Вы там бы лишним ниразу не были. :) А у потолочных плинтусов - туева хуча названий (про багет я сто лет в курсе), а экзотичное - не помню, ТБМ.

Comment: @ExMuser Да мне и тут неплохо. Что такое АШ?